# Sort Dictionary in Swift without downcast

Tags: swift

The difference between my problem and others is that I've known how to sort the dictionary with `sorted` in the closure.

```
struct Time {
    var offset = 0
    var duration = 0
}

let sortedLyricDict = lyricDict.sorted { $0.0.offset < $1.0.offset }
```

However, `var lyricDict: [Time: Character]` has been downcast to `let sortedLyricDict: [(key: Time, value: Character)]` instead of the original type. So I want to know whether the problem could be solved, thanks.

Comment: A dictionary is unordered by definition. It cannot be sorted. Applying `sorted` to a dictionary converts it to an **array** of tuples. If you need a collection type with a specific order use an array.

Comment: Sort works on collections, and a dictionary is a collection of tuples, thus the result you see. If you want a dictionary back, you need to reconstruct it from the array of tuples

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've changed the type of return value to handle the situation.